# ComboBox não esta sendo preenchido pelos Itens que eu quero

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-studio-2017

Tenho um ComboBox preenchido a partir de uma lista criada com informação obtida a partir de um arquivo txt. Mas na vez de ser preenchido com as informações do arquivo ele esta recebendo dentro dele isso -----> `GeraRelatorio.Planta`, gostaria de saber por quê?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateInicial.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    dateFinal.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    textBox1.MaxLength = 20;

    comboBanco.Items.Clear();
    List<Planta> plantas = new List<Planta>();

    using (StreamReader arquivo = File.OpenText(@"C:\Conexoes\Estados.txt"))
    {
        string linha;
        while ((linha = arquivo.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var espaçoArquivo = linha.Split(';');

            var planta = new Planta();
            planta.Local = espaçoArquivo[0];
            planta.Conexao = espaçoArquivo[1];

            plantas.Add(planta);
        }

    }

    foreach (Planta result in plantas)
    {
        comboBanco.Items.Add(result);
    }


}

private void comboBanco_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBanco.SendToBack();
    FrmGrid formb = new FrmGrid();

    switch (((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local)
    {
        case "CT":
            formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
            formb.lblConexao.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Conexao;
            formb.Show();
            break;

        case "CU":
            formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
            formb.lblConexao.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Conexao;
            formb.Show();
            break;

        case "AT":
            formb.lblLocal.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Local;
            formb.lblConexao.Text = ((Planta)comboBanco.SelectedItem).Conexao;
            formb.Show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

class Planta
{
    public string Local { get; set; }
    public string Conexao { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Porque você está adicionando na sua lista de items `comboBanco.Items.Add(result);` a instância de uma planta! Acho que deveria passar essa lista para o seu DataSource!

Comment: faça como Virgilio falou (apesar de não fazer diferença no problema citado), basta `comboBanco.DataSource = plantas;` e remove aquele foreach...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como você está preenchendo seu `combobox` com uma lista de uma entidade, precisamos informar qual campo dessa classe representa a descrição que será demonstrada e o valor que essa descrição representa.

Defina um valor (lembrando que deve ser alguma propriedade da sua classe `Planta`) para a propriedade `DisplayMember` do seu `combobox` para apresentar o texto para o usuário:

```
comboBanco.DisplayMember = "Local";
```

Defina um valor (lembrando que deve ser alguma propriedade da sua classe `Planta`) para a propriedade `ValueMember` do seu `combobox` para definir o valor para o item selecionado:

```
comboBanco.ValueMember = "Conexao";
```

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de adicionar uma `Planta` em seu `ComboBox`, adicione um `SelectListItem`.

```
foreach (Planta result in plantas)
{
    var item = new SelectListItem() { Text = result.Local, Value = result.Conexao }
    comboBanco.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: funciona, mas discordo. Se precisar pegar a "Planta" selecionada, é mais simples fazer: `Planta p = comboBanco.SelectedValue as Planta;`